# New Evaporator has bent fins

Tags: ac, hvac

I bought a new evaporator to replace my old leaky one.

However it has some fins bent.

Should I return the evaporator? Or should I try to get a new one?

EDIT: I just figured out what happened, this unit was shipped to my country and the customs guy ran a paper cutter through the package to open it for inspection. I think the blade crushed and cut the fins a bit. :(

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The folks who posted answers are all mighty tolerant. I wouldn't accept a new part that looked like it fell off the back of a truck.  Ask who sold it to you, in case it leaks, will the warranty cover *all* the costs, (labor, gas etc) to replace it?

Comment: One, the warranty on a part never (in my experience) covers the labour : starters , alternators etc... Two, every "new" one I have seen (evaporator, condensor, even radiators ) has minor surface danage to the fins and it is possible to straighten them - but the percentage reduction makes it hardly worth it - also consider a few months time with all the bugs leaves etc...

Comment: Of course they will not cover anything but the part. Its important that the OP should know that, and its a good question to ask if the parts guy says "don't worry about it its warranted" when you try to return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. There's nothing wrong with it. The bent fins might restrict airflow a little bit, but it's not going to cause huge issues. As long as there aren't any holes, you're golden.

If you want to, use a piece of sharp, pointed wood to gently straighten them out. To make a pointed piece of wood, use a dowel about the size of a pencil and use a pencil sharper. They don't need to be perfect and the metal will be very flexible. Just take your time and make them as straight as your patience will allow.

Comment: On the last picture if you look closely, the fins look torn near the lower edges. Is that not going to be a problem?

Comment: No, not at all. As long as the tubes aren't perforated, you're in good shape. All the evap coil is going to be doing is transferring heat. The few little tears may reduce the efficiency of the coil, but it's nothing you'd ever notice when using the AC system of the vehicle. From what I can see in the pictures, the tubes are in perfect shape. Like I said, I don't see anything for you to worry about.

Comment: ♦ I some how had it in my mind that the coils have refrigerant running through them... :D

Comment: Well, actually, the coils *do* have refrigerant running through them ... the fins don't, though :P

Comment: ha ha yeah sorry, my bad. I meant the fins... :)

Answer (score 1):

So, that all looks minor - only the edges and no damage to the tubes - you could spend time straightening them but it should be ok to leave them as they are.